# Commands out of sync you can't run this command now

Tags: python, mysql, synchronization, mysql-python

I am trying to create some tables using mysqldb.

The issue is that when executing the python script `db.py` mysql throws the error:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

db.py:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

def init_db():
    db_conn = get_db_conn()
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()

    with open("tables.sql", 'r') as f:
        cursor.execute(f.read())

def get_db_conn():
    return MySQLdb.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="secretcat",
        db="uptrender",
        cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
    )

init_db()
```

tables.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;

CREATE TABLE Test (
    id INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Test2 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Test(id)
);
```

According to the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) this error is given when client functions are called in the wrong order. Looking at the ones i use (i only have 3 i think) they look to be in the correct order. First connecting to the database, getting the cursor and finally excecuting the query to create tables. Is this the wrong order? It would not seem logical to do the query before connecting to the database...

EDIT: I tried closing the connection after populating the database with tables but it makes no difference.

EDIT2: Furthermore i tried to drop the database completely and re-create it but mysql still throws the same error.

EDIT3: I found that if i remove the two `DROP TABLES IF EXISTS tablename`-statements in the top of `tables.sql` i do not get the error. But only the first table (test) seems to have been created (using `SHOW TABLES;` in the mysql command line client to verify this)! What the heck is going on there?

EDIT4: So i isolated the problem further, it had nothing to do with flask.

Comment: Have you heard of SQLAlchemy? There's a version for Flask and it handles lots of this stuff for you and provides lots of other fun goodies

Comment: @timthompson Thanks for the tip, gonna check it out later!

Comment: @TimThompson But i really want to know what is going on here aswell!

Comment: Try `cursor.execute(f.read(), multi=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i figured out that i have to execute the statements one by one. I now do this:

```
from flask import current_app, g

import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

def init_db():
    db_conn = get_db_conn()
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    f = current_app.open_resource("tables.sql")
    tables = f.read().decode('utf-8').split(';')
    f.close()
    for table in tables:
        table = re.sub('[\n\r]', '', table)
        if len(table) > 0:
            cursor.execute(table)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but **I encountered the same error** while using the **`executemany`** method to run the same query with multiple parameters, and was unable to find a solution anywhere. So, if you’re reading this and experiencing the same issue, **try removing the semicolon from your SQL statement**. This resolved the issue for me.

As shown in the example from the documentation, which has no semicolons ([10.5.8 MySQLCursor.executemany() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)):

```
data = [
  ('Jane', date(2005, 2, 12)),
  ('Joe', date(2006, 5, 23)),
  ('John', date(2010, 10, 3)),
]
stmt = "INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue.

I had dumped my SQL insert statements into a .sql file to transfer data from two environments that had no other way of talking to each other.

One such file looked like this:

```
USE `myDatabase`;
INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES (
    some_value, some_value, some_value
);
```

My Python code was reading the file contents literally and running:

```
print(f"Inserting data in to the `{database}` database...")
print("Running:\n"+ insert_query)
cursor.execute(insert_query)
cursor.close()
cnx.commit()
```

and I was ending up with the same error as OP.

I solved it by removing the `USE myDatabase` statement in the .sql file and running instead:

```
print(f"Inserting data in to the `{database}` database...")
cursor.execute("USE myDatabase")
cursor.close()
print("Running:\n"+ insert_query)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert_query)
cursor.close()
cnx.commit()
```

and that solved the issue. Now, **this is still not good enough for production because I am not using an SQL statement**, which I read is insecure. For my purposes it was more than sufficient but it is something to keep in mind. For the right way to construct these insert statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html