# Python Error:Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, string

Here is the scenario, 
I am facing the error

```
Error:Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I need to pass the string to MYSQL which is a mixture of double and Single quotes. But when the mysql parsing the string it couldnt process the parameters because Python converting `""` to `''`.
for example

```
temp = "users= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(users, '$', 'user1'), users= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(users, '$', 'user2')"
```

converted to

```
temp = 'users= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(users, \'$\', \'user1\'), users= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(users, \'$\', \'user2\')'



sql = "Insert into User(internal_id, users) values(16, IFNULL(users->'$',JSON_ARRAY())); Update User SET " + temp + " where internal_id = 16;"
```

How to hanndle this Scenario?
Thanks

Comment: it doesnt appear that any " are changed to '. The quotes on the outside are not part of the string. It is just adding escape characters to the string. Can you provide the code where you use `temp`?

Comment: @DVL updated the code

Comment: The error you post has nothing to do with quotes, it means you haven't closed the cursor for the previous SQL statement, so the client thinks it still has more results to fetch. This is especially true after calling a stored procedure, because procedures return multiple result sets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: @Bill Karwin, I stopped the application and after re-running the application, i still face the same error. and I am closing the cursor connections after doing the operations.

Comment: Are you using the mysql connection in multiple threads? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755572/why-still-has-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now-error

Comment: Another option: you should run the INSERT and the UPDATE separately. Don't try to combine them into one `execute()` call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040054/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: Running Insert and update together caused the issue!!!Working now
Thanks @Bill Karwin

Answer (score 0):

Based on searching past Stack Overflow questions related to the error:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

This problem is caused by executing multiple SQL statements in the same call to `execute()`. You can't do that unless you pass the argument `multi=True`.

This is the same solution as the one reported in [Commands out of sync you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040054/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

But there is no reason to use multi-statements. It is easier and more clear to write your code to execute one SQL statement at a time.

The former Engineering Manager for MySQL once told me, "there is no reason for MySQL to support multi-statements." They just make writing code more difficult, and they don't give you any advantage to performance or anything else.

Comment: I already tried with multi=True before posting this question, But that's not working even now, couldn't figure out why!! Only if I execute both as seperate queries.. Its working otherwise throwing me an `Error:Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: Then run the statements separately. That's what I do.

Comment: Yes @Bill Karwin !!